# CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am triing to run a script in pgAdmin 4, but I get this error:

```
CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

And this is the script:

```
CREATE USER ky_auth WITH PASSWORD 'ky_auth';
COMMENT ON ROLE ky_auth IS 'KnowYourself Auth Database User';
CREATE DATABASE ky_auth WITH OWNER = ky_auth;
COMMENT ON DATABASE ky_auth IS 'KnowYourself Auth Database';

CREATE USER ky_pers WITH PASSWORD 'ky_pers';
COMMENT ON ROLE ky_pers IS 'KnowYourself Personal Database User';
CREATE DATABASE ky_pers WITH OWNER = ky_pers;
COMMENT ON DATABASE ky_pers IS 'KnowYourself Personal Database';

CREATE USER ky_oper WITH PASSWORD 'ky_oper';
COMMENT ON ROLE ky_oper IS 'KnowYourself Operational Database User';
CREATE DATABASE ky_oper WITH OWNER = ky_oper;
COMMENT ON DATABASE ky_oper IS 'KnowYourself Operational Database';

CREATE USER knowyourself_tests WITH PASSWORD 'ky_tests' CREATEDB;
COMMENT ON ROLE knowyourself_tests IS 'KnowYourself Integration Tests Database User';
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

and if put this above the script:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON
```

Then I get this error:

```
 unrecognized configuration parameter "autocommit"
```

if I do this:

```
CREATE USER ky_auth WITH PASSWORD 'ky_auth';
COMMENT ON ROLE ky_auth IS 'KnowYourself Auth Database User';
```

then it succeeds. but then If I do this:

```
CREATE DATABASE ky_auth WITH OWNER = ky_auth;
COMMENT ON DATABASE ky_auth IS 'KnowYourself Auth Database';
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

Comment: This is essentially the same thing: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/drop-multiple-databases-in-one-script
Need to run 'create' separately in pgAdmin or use commandline `psql`

Answer (score 4):

If there is no `BEGIN;` or `START TRANSACTION;` anywhere in your script, then pgAdmin must send your whole script to the database as a single “multi-statement”.

In that case you have to select and execute the `CREATE DATABASE` statements one by one.

Consider using `psql` to make this work more comfortably.

Comment: Ok, then maybe ma modified answer has the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

AUTOCOMMIT is removed after 9.5. You need to run

```sql
\set autocommit on
```

Pay attention to the backslash `\` in the beginning.

Afterwards your db creation query should work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be slightly over simplifying things, but to work around this issue I simply highlight the individual statements and run them one at a time. That way pgadmin doesn't sent them in a transaction e.g.

first:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'olddb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

(highlight the above and execute it)

Then

```
CREATE DATABASE yournewdb
    WITH 
    OWNER = USER
    TEMPLATE = olddb
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

execute that

then finally (and somewhat needlessly)

```
COMMENT ON DATABASE yournewdb
    IS 'The development instance of the olddb database. Will be destroyed and recreated at short notice.';
```